# Embedding a Spotify Play Button within Carto.db map infowindow

Tags: spotify, cartodb

been trying to find a solve for embedding a Spotify play button within an infowindow within Carto.db (or any other open source location intelligence platform).

The closest I've seen is this user's solve (http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/d5524a6513fee65e3065), however it doesn't actually display the play button, just a link to the Spotify song.

Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ey that block is mine :) there you see how to add your own custom infowindow with javascript enabled. That's only possible with CartoDB.js because CartoDB can't allow that at the editor for security reasons. So the only thing you need apart from that example is instructions on how to add the embed that according to [spotify docs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/) looks like a regular iframe.